# Why wouldn't I want to use the newest version of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I do mostly google app engine coding, and a little bit of android development, and don't understand why I wouldn't want my Eclipse ide to always be at the most recent release, or version. It seems like there are some plugins that wouldn't be compatible, but couldn't you just install the missing features from an old release of Eclipse into the newest release?

Comment: Seems like a bit of an obvious question to me - if everything you need works with the latest release of Eclipse, use the latest release? Has someone told you not to?

Comment: @berry120: Everything I need to work does work. I'm just confused as to why everyone wouldn't want to upgrade. Upgrading from Galileo to Helios hasn't really changed any features that I use every day except added Git built in, and added a market. If features aren't regularly removed, then what's wrong with keeping up to date with releases?

Comment: People don't upgrade for various reasons - some are lazy, some are afraid a new version will introduce more bugs and some just like sticking with what they know works. That doesn't make upgrading a crime however, I generally stick with the latest versions of software when I can (unless I know it's introduced a nasty bug or two.) If you want to upgrade, do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the predominant reason for not upgrading is lack of support for the new release from the plugins that you require. You cannot just install "missing features". Most of the time, the incompatibility is due to changes in the new version of an existing feature. Plugins that ship from eclipse.org are tested together in coordinated releases. While in some cases, it may be possible to down-version a plugin and have that plugin still work in the new version of Eclipse, it is not something that you can depend on working. In fact, the odds of this working without issues are so small, that I wouldn't bother trying.

Stick with whatever version of Eclipse your required plugins support until those plugins upgrade their support. If they aren't moving fast enough, consider pestering the provider about this issue. If nothing else, knowing how big of a chunk of the community cares about support for the latest version of Eclipse will help the plugin provider prioritize their work.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that always having the most up to date version of *program x* really isn't necessary.  I think the most important thing is having a set of tools that you know how to use well.  Upgrade those tools when there is a reason to do so, not just because there is a new version of them.

Comment: And never, _never_ upgrade to a version that ends in .0  :-)

Comment: It depends - if having the latest version of program x doesn't change the interface but improves on speed, efficiency and fixes a few bugs I don't see the logic in not upgrading. Even if you haven't been affected by those bugs previously there's no guarantee you won't be in the future.

Comment: @Adam: the same concept applies to cars as well.:)

Comment: @berry120: that's true.  I'd call that a reason for upgrading.

Comment: Improved IDE-Features are always a good Reason to Upgrade. Just use Target Platforms, so you don't have to migrate the project to a newer Eclipse Version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that. If you want to compile against an older Eclipse version, this can be done very easily.

e.g. if you want to develop with Eclipse 3.6:

- download Eclipse 3.5 and extract it (e.g. c:\development\targetplatforms\eclipse3.5).
- start Eclipse 3.6, choose your workspace where you want to use the Target Platform.
- open the Menu Window->Preferences, type target in the search field, and add a new Target Platform (Nothing: Start with an empty target definition -> Add -> Direcotry -> choose the unzipped Eclipse 3.5)

There are some advantages of using a target platform. You have the newest IDE Features. You can build your product against older Eclipse Versions without having to port it to your newses IDE version. You can add Plugins to your Target Platform without contaminating your ide or add Plugins to your IDE withoud contaminating your Target Platform. ...

You should bundle your Target Platform with your Project, so you don't have to download it again. We have a TargetPlatform Project in our SVN Repostory. Every Project has a small readme how to setup the Workspace (targetplatform, deployment, ....).

Answer (score 0):

> Why wouldn't I want to use the newest version of Eclipse?

Because IntelliJ IDEA provides a Community Edition. :)

Comment: ...that doesn't provide Google app engine support, which is one of the main tasks of the OP!

Comment: I know... bad joke, sorry ! I just couldn't help it, but I should have posted this as a comment rather than an answer...

Comment: In fairness, if the OP was just doing android work, I'd say it was a perfectly valid answer since the community edition now supports Android :-)